# Create delegate reflection

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have an event bus setup (using Redbus) to handle events in my game. I would like to have an attribute that automatically registers a function to my event bus.

I would normally register an event like:

```
public void RegisterEvents()
{
    EVENT_BUS.Subscribe<InitializationEvent>(this.OnInit);
}

public void OnInit(InitializationEvent e)
{
}
```

but I'd ideally just do

```
[EventHandler]
public void OnInit(InitializationEvent e)
{
}
```

I have the code to iterate through my classes and methods to get every method with an EventHandler attribute but when I try to create a delegate to register with my event bus I get this error

```
ArgumentException: method arguments are incompatible
```

Here is my code:

```
private void SetupEventHandlers()
    {
        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (var _class in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (!_class.IsClass)
                    continue;

                foreach (var method in _class.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
                {
                    if (!method.IsDefined(typeof(EventHandler), false))
                        continue;

                    if (method.IsStatic)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("Cannot use EventHandler attribute on static fields");
                        continue;
                    }

                    var parameters = method.GetParameters();
                    var eventType = parameters[0].ParameterType;

                    var a = Activator.CreateInstance(_class);

                    var d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(Expression.GetActionType(method.GetType()), a, method);

                    //do rest of registration stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to get this working?

Comment: This approach is less type safe, less performant, and less readable than using the built in event system in the language

Comment: Why not simply `Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<InitializationEvent>), a, method)`?

Comment: Looks like you're coming to Unity after having been modding in Minecraft Forge for a while. Sorry to break it to you, but you're never going to get what you want, as C# is a lot stricter about types than Java is. That said, you might want to look at [this class](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CSharpMessenger_Extended). Its all 100% ready to go and will do what you want. Personally I removed the string parameter and just got the <T> object's class name instead. Plus some other tweaks (I didn't like the Broadcast's callback method and wanted to have modifiable event objects).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that [EventHandler] refers to an EventHandlerAtttribute class.
Then method.IsDefined(typeof(EventHandler), false) should also be method.IsDefined(typeof(EventHandlerAtttribute), false).

Comment: In your normal way of working, the RegisterEvents is based on an instance of the class. In your suggested approach you do not work with an instance? Do I miss something?